# Using ternary and arrow function to solve a freeCodeCamp Exercise

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using this function:

```
let factorialize = (num) => (num === 0) || (num * factorialize(num -1));

factorialize(5);
```

then I get this.

> factorialize(0) should return 1.

but everything else seems right.

Comment: depending on how you test it it is 1 :D num===0  returns true which evalutes to 1 if you use it in an addition for example to make sure you can do (num) => +(num === 0)...
(pretty sure that works on booleans)

Comment: Probably clearer just to use a real ternary here: `let factorialize = (num) => num === 0 ? 1 : (num * factorialize(num -1));
`

Comment: Mark you're awesome;